# Fetch data based on selection using EJS and express

Tags: express, ejs

I have a page called magic.ejs. There I have a form with 2 fields.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    <button type="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

When I submit, I'd like to go to a new page `magiclist.ejs`. There, i'd like to have access to the 2 fields I filled in.

In my index file i have my route defined:

```
app.get("/magiclist", (req, res) => {
  //somehow get the values I filled in here? 
  res.render("magiclist", { magicNpcList: magicNpcList });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use query params for that purpose. You call a URL like `/magiclist?name=<nameHere>&email=<emailHere>`

And then grab the parameters on the other side like this:

```
app.get("/magiclist", (req, res) => {
  const {name, email} = req.query;
  res.render("magiclist", { magicNpcList: magicNpcList });
});
```